# Visual Studio 2013 - turning off indenting does not work?

Tags: visual-studio

Ok - I want indenting turned off in Visual Studio Pro 2013, so...

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Tabs -> Indenting (set to None) -> Click OK

Now, no matter what type of file I edit I get indented text, code, comments; I have indents coming out of my ears !

It's a cruel joke right?  Or am I the only person who thought setting Tabs -> Indenting to None meant none?

What magic am I missing? -- and yes, I have found similar posts and NONE (sorry for the pun) of the solutions have worked yet ...

Seriously though -- I know I missed some setting -- but for the life of me I cannot disable this behavior.

Comment: It works for me. Does it work if you set Indenting to None for individual file type instead of all languages?

Comment: No -- nothing seems to disable this behavior -- for example, when I edit an .aspx file, if the cursor is in left-most column and I hit the return key, the cursor goes to the next line but indents 6 characters !  How do you turn this OFF??

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sffa753.aspx - None 
When selected, new lines are not indented. The insertion point is placed in the first column of a new line.
So why when I insert a new line is my cursor in column 6? -- I have set the indent option to NONE for ALL languages?????  This is driving me NUTS !!!